# Environment variables on Linux-like systems

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

How to set environment variables for a user in most generic way that is independent of shell environment variables (like profile for Bourne-like shells, bahsrc, zshrc, zshenv, ..)?
The idea is to set environment variables for a user during user login and make them available (forked) for any process (spawned not only by shell process, but rather by any other process) including any kind of shell?

Comment: Different syntaxes. Check on which [shell you are working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327013/how-to-determine-the-current-shell-im-working-on) and parse a file with all the variable transforming the syntax to the correct one. Remember the back compatibility of the shells to reduce the work.

Comment: And do not ask how to parse current shell environment to another shell environment configuration? It rather how to set env variables without any shell at all, but read the whole question please.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/375252/what-is-the-best-place-to-setup-system-wide-environment-variables-on-linux

Answer (score 1):

[This Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) talks about `~/.pam_environment`:

> ### Session-wide environment variables
>
> Suitable files for environment
>   variable settings that should affect just a particular user (rather
>   than the system as a whole) are `~/.pam_environment` and `~/.profile`.
>   After having edited one of those files, you should **re-login** in order
>   to initialize the variables.
>
> #### `~/.pam_environment`
>
> This file is specifically meant for setting a user’s environment. It
>   is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions,
>   one per line. This example sets the variable FOO to a literal string
>   and modifies the PATH variable:
>
> ```
> FOO=bar
> PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:${HOME}/MyPrograms
> ```
>
> Note:
>
> 1. You may not quote the value when doing a simple variable assignment
>      like the `FOO=bar` example.
> 2. The syntax used for modifying PATH, which syntax differs from script
>      files, is required for variable expansion to work.
> 3. `~/.pam_environment`
>      is written to when you use various GUIs to set the language or
>      regional formats. Consequently, if you for instance set LC_TIME by
>      editing `~/.pam_environment` manually, your entry will be overwritten if
>      you afterwards use the Language Support GUI to change the regional
>      formats setting.

This file, as well as `/etc/environment`, seems to be consulted by [`pam_env.so`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_env) which I believe would happen as part of the login process and would be separate from any shell.